# Parse values from JSON body

Tags: python, json, pandas, parsing, jsonparser

I have the attached following actions parameter part of my JSON data.

```
'actions': [{'action_type': 'onsite_conversion.post_save', 'value': '1'},
  {'action_type': 'link_click', 'value': '2'},
  {'action_type': 'post', 'value': '3'},
  {'action_type': 'post_reaction', 'value': '4'},
  {'action_type': 'video_view', 'value': '5'},
  {'action_type': 'post_engagement', 'value': '6'},
  {'action_type': 'page_engagement', 'value': '7'}],
```

API can send the following options at any time;

```
action_types = ["onsite_conversion.post_save", "link_click", "post", "post_reaction", "comment", "video_view", "post_engagement", "page_engagement"]
```

I tried to write a python script that parses these possible values (**in action_types list order**) from the JSON body, as seen from the sample JSON data it doesn't send **comment** value so in this case script should write 0 to return list, below is my script

```
def get_action_values(insight):
    action_types = ["onsite_conversion.post_save", "link_click", "post", "post_reaction", 
                "comment", "video_view", "post_engagement", "page_engagement"]
    action_type_values = []
    
    for action in action_types:
        if action in [item["action_type"] for item in insight["actions"]]:
            for item in insight["actions"]:
                if action in item["action_type"]:
                    if "value" in item:
                        action_type_values.append(item["value"])
                    else:
                        action_type_values.append("Null")
        else:
            action_type_values.append(0)
    return action_type_values
```

I am expecting it to return as `[1,2,3,4,0,5,6,7]` but it returned as `[1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 6, 4, 0, 5, 6, 7]`

Comment: `if action in item["action_type"]:` should be `if action == item["action_type"]:`. Your condition is true when an action type is a substring, e.g. `post` is in `onsite_conversion.post_save`

Comment: @buran I think he's asking why he's getting all the extra values, not why they're in quotes.

Comment: @Barmar, the expected list has numbers from 1 to 7, the actual - string literals from `'1'` to `'7'`

Comment: Barmar is right, there are extra values and I am missing one point in my function.

Comment: The problem @buran points out can be resolved by using `append(int(item["value"]))`

Comment: Which action type are you missing?

Comment: Barmar, thank you if action == item["action_type"]: this solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the code you posted and as it was already pointed out in the comments to your question:

```
{'action_type': 'link_click', 'value': '2'},
```

`'value'` has a value of `'2'` not `2`, so if you expect integers in the resulting list use:

```
if "value" in item:
   action_type_values.append(int(item["value"]))
```

or to be consistent with the string representation:

```
else:
    action_type_values.append("0")
```

Another issue was caused by the if-condition `if action in item["action_type"]:` you use because you have an action type `'post'` which occur in all of `'onsite_conversion.post_save'`, `'post'`, `'post_reaction'` and `'post_engagement'`also containing `'post'`, so it is necessary to change the condition (as pointed out by *barmar* in the comments) to: `if action == item["action_type"]:` to eliminate duplicates in the result.

Below the entire corrected code:

```
dct_json = {'actions': [
  {'action_type': 'onsite_conversion.post_save', 'value': '1'},
  {'action_type': 'link_click', 'value': '2'},
  {'action_type': 'post', 'value': '3'},
  {'action_type': 'post_reaction', 'value': '4'},
  {'action_type': 'video_view', 'value': '5'},
  {'action_type': 'post_engagement', 'value': '6'},
  {'action_type': 'page_engagement', 'value': '7'}],
}
# API can send the following options at any time;
action_types = ["onsite_conversion.post_save", "link_click", "post", "post_reaction", "comment", "video_view", "post_engagement", "page_engagement"]

def get_action_values(insight):
    action_types = ["onsite_conversion.post_save", "link_click", "post", "post_reaction", 
                "comment", "video_view", "post_engagement", "page_engagement"]
    action_type_values = []
    
    for action in action_types:
        if action in [item["action_type"] for item in insight["actions"]]:
            for item in insight["actions"]:
                if action == item["action_type"]:
                    if "value" in item:
                        action_type_values.append(int(item["value"]))
                    else:
                        action_type_values.append("Null")
        else:
            action_type_values.append(0)
    return action_type_values
print( get_action_values(dct_json) )
```

printing the expected:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 5, 6, 7]
```

---

Animated by *Jamiu S.* answer which tries to optimize the code but does generally not work properly ( as of 2023-02-05 01:06 CET ) failing with KeyError or not printing all the values, below improved code eliminating one loop and using `dictionary.get(key, default_value)` syntax to eliminate an `if/else` code section.
The code includes changed input data to show that it covers cases in which the code in *Jamiu S.* answer fails to work or to work properly. Notice that the returned list items are all strings to be consistent with `'Null'` and the `'action_type'` values:

```
dct_json = {'actions': [
  {'action_type': 'onsite_conversion.post_save', 'value': '1'},
  {'action_type': 'link_click',                  'value': '2'},
  {'action_type': 'page_engagement-no-value', 'no-value': '8'},
  {'action_type': 'post',                        'value': '3'},
  {'action_type': 'post_reaction',               'value': '4'},
  {'action_type': 'video_view',                  'value': '5'},
  {'action_type': 'post_engagement',             'value': '6'},
  {'action_type': 'page_engagement',             'value': '7'},
  {'action_type': 'post',                        'value': '33'},
]}
action_types = ["onsite_conversion.post_save", "link_click", "post", 
        "post_reaction", "comment", "video_view", "post_engagement", 
        "page_engagement", "page_engagement-no-value"]

def get_action_values(insight, action_types):
    action_type_values = []
    for action in action_types:
        lstofmatchingitems = [ item for item in insight["actions"] if item["action_type"]==action ]
        if lstofmatchingitems:
            for item in lstofmatchingitems:
                action_type_values.append(item.get("value", "Null"))
        else:
            action_type_values.append("0")
    return action_type_values
print(get_action_values(dct_json, action_types))
```

prints

```
['1', '2', '3', '33', '4', '0', '5', '6', '7', 'Null']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def create_columns_from_dict_list(dataframe, column_name):
    # Go through each row in the column_name column
    for index, row in dataframe.iterrows():
        # List the dictionaries from the column_name column of this string
        value_row = row[column_name]
        if pd.notna(value_row) and value_row:
            dict_list = eval(value_row)

            # Go through each dictionary in the list
            for dictionary in dict_list:
                # Extract 'action_type' and 'value' from the dictionary
                if 'action_type' in dictionary:
                    action_type = dictionary['action_type']
                    new_column = f'{action_type}'
                    value = dictionary['value']

                    # Create a new column
                    dataframe.at[index, new_column] = float(value)


    # Fill empty NaN values with zeros
    dataframe[new_column] = dataframe[new_column].fillna(0)

    # Convert column values to numeric data type
    dataframe[new_column] = dataframe[new_column].astype(float)

    # Delete the current column
    dataframe.pop(column_name)

    return dataframe
```

Answer (score -1):

***Here is a possible solution:***
The `action_type_values` list is initialized with zeros of the length -> [`len()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len) of `action_types` which represents the default value for any missing `action_type` in the insight dictionary.

The `for-loop` then loops through all the actions for each action, if `action_type` is in `action_types`, it's [index](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/list/lindex.html) is found and the corresponding value in the `action_type_values` is updated with the `int(value)` of the action.

```py
def get_action_values(insight):
    action_types = ["onsite_conversion.post_save", "link_click", "post", "post_reaction", "comment", "video_view", "post_engagement", "page_engagement"]
    action_type_values = [0] * len(action_types)
    
    for item in insight["actions"]:
        if item["action_type"] in action_types:
            idx = action_types.index(item["action_type"])
            action_type_values[idx] = int(item["value"])
    return action_type_values

print(get_action_values(my_json))
```

---

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 5, 6, 7]
```